# How to write an ITranslationUnit to a file

Tags: parsing, eclipse-cdt, automated-refactoring

There is no setPath function as a part of the translationunit. so how does one save it to another file? (a file different from the one it parsed)

I have been able to parse a C++ file (in a java program outside of Eclipse using the jars) and get a working ITranslationUnit from it. I want to modify a declaration. And then save the modification to file. But I see no examples anywhere to do that.

I understand there is a "working copy" of the translationunit to deal with too.

Comment: How are you doing the "modify a declaration" part?

Comment: That is the problem, I haven't done it. That is what I would like to do.

Comment: The best way is probably using `ASTRewrite`. [This document](https://eprints.hsr.ch/79/1/cdt_c++.pdf) might provide some details that are useful.